# Using Method Cast instead of Lambda on List with Objects

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am working on fixing some Sonar - Codesmells in my project at the moment.
Sonar is pointing me at this method:

```java
    protected List<Long> rolesIdsFromPortalSpecificAuthorizations(final List<PortalSpecificAuthorization> portalSpecificAuthorizations) {
             return portalSpecificAuthorizations.stream().map(portalSpecificAuthorization -> portalSpecificAuthorization.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

It says:

> Replace this lambda with a method reference.

The `PortalSpecificAuthorization` is an object from my own coding. I was not able to find an easy-to-use solution for this case with Method casts.
What is the correct usage in this case?

Comment: [Method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sonar wants a Method Reference instead of the lambda.

Replace this part:

```java
portalSpecificAuthorization -> portalSpecificAuthorization.getId()
```

with this

```
PortalSpecificAuthorization::getId
```

More about Method References: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-8-method-reference

---

Full Code:

```java
protected List<Long> rolesIdsFromPortalSpecificAuthorizations(final List<PortalSpecificAuthorization> portalSpecificAuthorizations) {
    return portalSpecificAuthorizations.stream()
              .map(PortalSpecificAuthorization::getId)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Ah okay. Up until now, i allways could use objects (or references like 'this') to call the Method. In fact, i tried to implement it like your suggestion before. What i didnt know and you could not know: the method to get the ID does not come from the Class itself in this case, it comes from a parent class. I need to use the parentclass in this case, like this:

`return portalSpecificAuthorizations.stream().map(Persistable::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @mirco no, you don’t need to use the superclass. Since `PortalSpecificAuthorization` inherits the method, using `PortalSpecificAuthorization::getId` should work as well.